# After how many days of inactivity, twilio resets the auth_token for an account?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

After some days of inactivity, Twilio resets the auth token for an account for security reasons. After the auth token is updated, API calls to Twilio fails due to authentication issue. Can somebody answer the exact number of days after which the auth token is reset so that I can request a new auth token before it is expired?

I have tried to look for any documentation regarding this but did not find anything.
[Twilio alert after the Auth Token is updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqNyq.png)

Comment: This sounds strange. My auth token has never been reset. Are you referring to the AUTH_TOKEN you see in the console as mentioned [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/credentials/api)?

Comment: yes @IObert. I am attaching a screenshot of the alert that pops on your account when Twilio resets the Auth token.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I never observed this behavior and I'd recommend to reach out to support. But I could also see that this might not be a static rule and maybe uses a combination of patterns. So I'm not sure if there is a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I reached out to Twilio support about it and this was their response:

> Yes, the automated reset of auth tokens is a security feature that is
> enabled on all accounts for protection.  We do this out of an
> abundance of caution as we need to be vigilant against bad actors who
> take advantage of customers who leak their tokens or abandon their
> accounts and may not notice unauthorized intrusion into their
> accounts.

> Unfortunately, we are not at the liberty to share the time
> duration of the auth token reset period for best security practices.
> We advise you to adopt a schedule to reset or log in any accounts
> which might end up inactive for a time period.